# How I fix ns3's " Program "/waf" not found in PATH" error that it appears within eclipse?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ns-3

I use ns3.30 and I configured it to build and run within Eclipse. However, I continuously get this error
"Error: Program "/waf" not found in PATH
PATH=[/bin:/home/flower/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]"
despite that everything working fine. Does that mean that am I may face a problem with my ns3 project later?, or, can I safely discard that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/waf` refers to `waf` in the root directory. The problem is that you don't have a `waf` in the root directory. Change the path to `./waf` to refer to `waf` the current working directory.

If you don't fix this, then any script you write will first have to be manually compiled by running `./waf` from the terminal.